# Convert double into hex in C#

Tags: c#, .net, double, hex

I have this value:

```
double headingAngle = 135.34375;
```

I would like to convert it to HEX and print the HEX to the console. I have already converted a string and int into their respective HEX values, but a double seems to be much more tricky. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: One reason there is no ready-made function for this is because it is utterly useless. Who can (and wants to) read a double as hex?

Comment: agree with Henk. @rross: I am dying to know, why do you need to do this?

Comment: @Henk There's nothing inherently less useful about representing a non-integer value in hex than in decimal or any other base. We're just more used to decimal.

Comment: there is no data type for hexadecimal. it is just a representation, data format. try looking into different ways of formatting the double. hope that makes sense.

Comment: Using headingAngle.ToString("X") works for ints and longs, but when I try to use it for a double the compiler states: "Format specifier was invalid".

Comment: @Henk: The hardware I'm working with requires all data to be represented in hex values. I could not answer beyond that.

Comment: @Jimmy: Not homework. I wanted to print to screen to make sure conversion was working.

Comment: @rross: then you will need to know precisely what (binary) format your hardware understands.

Comment: just answer the question or point him to the direction which does. why bully him?

Comment: For me at least I see multiple ways to interpret this question. 1- Do you want to show the integer and fractional portion as to hex values separated with a decimal point as in 87.8647, where 87 is hex of 135 and 8647 is hex of 34375. Or 2- do you want that 8 byte IEEE representation of the double shown in hex as in 0x4060EB0000000000?

Comment: Fractions can be validly represented in any radix! We just happened to have 10 fingers and hence decimal became entrenched!

Comment: If talking to hardware, yes. Otherwise it's not that exotic: 123.5 decimal == 7b.8 hexadecimal, 173.4 octal, 1111011.1 binary etc. I don't see why people think this "has no value".

Comment: @Henk, if I say 0x000000 will you say 0xFFFFFF? hehe

Comment: rross, I'm voting -1 because you did not specify the desired result (ie, what should 135.34375 look like in Hex). This question has turned into a guessing match.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/309/)
here is a quite elegant solution

```
    double d = 12.09;
    Console.WriteLine("Double value: " + d.ToString());
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(d);
    Console.WriteLine("Byte array value:");
    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(bytes));
```

Comment: I know this question is quite old, but it's probably worth pointing out that this code won't convert the value of the double to its hexadecimal representation. Rather, it'll write out the hex representation of the bits that are used to store the number internally. For a floating point number, the two are different things!

Comment: Point taken. Although I didn't heard of any standard of hex notation for representation of floating point values. Of course it is important to remember about the hardware spec and all the big/low endian stuff. However standard IEEE 754 is very popular and widely used. So..

Answer (score 4):

You can convert base 10 to base 16 by continually multiplying the fraction by 16, stripping out the 'whole' number, and repeating with the remainder.

So to convert 0.1 Decimal to Hex

```
0.1 * 16
= 1.6
```

So 1 becomes the first hex value. Keep going with the remaining 0.6

```
0.6 * 16 = 9.6
```

So 9 becomes the second hex value. Keeping going with the remaining 0.6

```
0.6 * 16 = 9.6
```

etc.

So `0.1` Decimal = `0.19999`.. recurring hex

From memory this works for any radix. Obviously in hex a whole value of `10` would be A etc.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to convert to hexadecimal base/radix, the following should do the trick:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Base16(135.34375, 10));
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static string Base16(double number, int fractionalDigits)
{
    return Base(number, fractionalDigits, new char[]{
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' });
}

private static string Base(double number, int fractionalDigits, params char[] characters)
{
    int radix = characters.Length;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // The 'whole' part of the number.
    long whole = (long)Math.Floor(number);
    while (whole > 1)
    {
        sb.Insert(0, characters[whole % radix]);
        whole = whole / radix;
    }

    // The fractional part of the number.
    double remainder = number % 1;
    if (remainder > Double.Epsilon || remainder < -Double.Epsilon)
    {
        sb.Append('.');

        double nv;
        for (int i = 0; i < fractionalDigits; i++)
        {
            nv = remainder * radix;
            if (remainder < Double.Epsilon && remainder > -Double.Epsilon)
                break;
            sb.Append(characters[(int)Math.Floor(nv)]);
            remainder = nv % 1;
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

The hexadecimal conversion of 135.34375 is `87.58`.

Answer (score 2):

```
BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(value).ToString("X")
```

Comment: it good idea to write some explanation about your answer ... what do you mean by `ToString("X")` ?have you tested before posting ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static string Format(double number, double @base)
{
    StringBuilder format = new StringBuilder();
    if(number < 0)
    {
        format.Append('-');
        number = -number;
    }
    double log = Math.Log(number, @base);
    bool frac = false;
    double order;
    if(log < 0)
    {
        frac = true;
        format.Append(digits[0]);
        format.Append('.');
        order = 1/@base;
    }else{
        order = Math.Pow(@base, Math.Floor(log));
    }
    while(number != 0 || order >= 1)
    {
        double digit = Math.Floor(number/order);
        if(digit >= @base) break;
        number = number-digit*order;
        number = Math.Round(number, 15);
        if(order < 1 && !frac)
        {
            format.Append('.');
            frac = true;
        }
        order /= @base;
        if(digit >= 10)
        {
            format.Append((char)('A'+(digit-10)));
        }else{
            format.Append((char)('0'+digit));
        }
    }
    return format.ToString();
}
```

Use it like `Format(headingAngle, 16)`. You can also comment out `number = Math.Round(number, 15);` for more interesting results. ☺

Result is in culture-invariant format. For 135.34375, it returns 87.58.